# Differentials on a Riemann surface as sections of certain vector bundle.

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface. According to Griffiths and Harris "Principles of Algebraic Geometry", the complexified tangent space of $X$ at $p\in X$ is 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T_{\mathbb{C},p}X=\{\xi:\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{C})_p\rightarrow\mathbb{C}:\xi(\lambda f+\mu g)=\lambda \xi(f)+\mu\xi(g)\text{ and}\\
\xi(fg)=g(p)\xi(f)+f(p)\xi(g)\text{ }\forall f,g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(X,\mathbb{C})_p,\text{ }\forall\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{C}\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We can consider its dual $T^*_{\mathbb{C},p}X=\{\alpha:T_{\mathbb{C},p}X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}:\alpha\text{ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear}\}$. Then, $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ $1$-forms are the sections of the bundle,
$$
T^*_\mathbb{C}X=\{(p,\alpha):p\in X, \alpha\in T^*_{\mathbb{C},p}X\}.
$$
In a chart they have the form
$$
f\cdot\mathrm{d}x+g\cdot\mathrm{d}y
$$
for some complex-valued $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ functions $f,g$.

On the other hand, we have the subbundle 
$$
\{(p,\alpha):p\in X, \alpha\in\mathbb{C}\cdot (\mathrm{d}z)_p\subseteq  T^*_{\mathbb{C},p}X\},
$$
where $(\mathrm{d}z)_p=(\mathrm{d}x)_p+i\cdot(\mathrm{d}y)_p$. If I am not wrong, type $(1,0)$ $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ $1$-forms are the sections of this subbundle. Hence, in a chart they have the form
$$
f\cdot dz
$$
for some complex-valued $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ function $f$.

Now, holomorphic $1$-forms are of the type
$$
f\cdot dz
$$
for some holomorphic function $f$.

I guess they are sections of some bundle (related with the previous one). What bundle are we talking about?

Comment: The complexified cotangent bundle; take a look in Griffiths and Harris "Principles of Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: Dear @MoisheCohen, first of all I wanted to thank you for the suggestion. Now, I have been reading Griffiths and Harris "Principles of Algebraic Geometry", but it is not clear for me yet. I have edited the question with my new doubts.

Comment: No, there is no reason for $f$ to be holomorphic for general $(1,0)$ forms $fdz$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen edited again.

Comment: @ZéPequeno: It's not clear to me from the edits what your confusion is. A $(1, 0)$-form is a smooth section of the $(1, 0)$-subbundle of the complexified cotangent bundle. A holomorphic $1$-form is a particular type of smooth $(1, 0)$-form, i.e., a section of the same complex line bundle. Since the $(1, 0)$-cotangent bundle is rank one, it has no proper, non-trivial (complex) subbundles.

Comment: Dear @AndrewD.Hwang, I think I understand now, thank you very much.

Comment: Just to emphasize: Holomorphic $1$-forms are sections of the bundle of $(1,0)$-forms that are annihilated by $\bar\partial$. This bundle is a *smooth* complex line bundle. You can also think of the *holomorphic* cotangent bundle, which is a holomorphic line bundle on a Riemann surface, and then consider its holomorphic sections.

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin, what is the definition of the holomorphic cotangent bundle? Thank you.